# Can a Java method in a sub class have the same signature as a method in the parent class but does not cause overriding?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, overriding

I have recently started learning Java and currently studying about polymorphism. Consider the following code :

```
    public class Polygon{
       public static void perimeter( ){
             System.out.print("In Polygon perimeter");
       }
       public void area( ){
             System.out.println("In Polygon area");
       }
       public void sides( ){
             System.out.println("In Polygon sides");
       }
       public void angleSum( ){
             System.out.println("In Polygon angleSum");
       }
  }
  public class Pentagon extends Polygon{
       public static void perimeter( ){
             System.out.println("In Pentagon perimeter");
       }
       public void area( ) {
             System.out.println("In Pentagon area");
       }
       public int sides( ){
              return 5;
       }
       public void angleSum(int x) {
             System.out.println("In Pentagon angleSum");
      }
  }
```

On executing this code, I find out that sides() method cannot be overridden. I understand in overriding, the method name and return type should be same but in this case return types are different. So, is there any way to execute it without causing overriding but keeping the same names and different types?

Comment: Why would you ever want this?

Comment: I saw similar in C# when I learned its first versions, if I'm not mistaken it's possible by using the `new` keyword in a subclass. There is nothing like this in Java, and Java uses virtual dispatch always (except static methods, and some other exclusions.)

Comment: sides() method cannot be overridden. what makes you think it can't be? problem here is: if you call sides(), how is the system supposed to know what you want? why would you want the same method name for two methods that do something completely unrelated?

Comment: You can make `sides()` method `private` or `static` in superclass to avoid polymorphism, but I am not sure is this would be good direction. For now your question looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*is there any way to execute it without causing overriding but keeping the same names and different types?*

Only if the method in the parent class is declared as `private`, no overriding takes place, but the method `sides` has very limited access so the following code in `Main.java` class fails:

```java
class Polygon {
    private void sides() {
        System.out.println("In Polygon sides");
    }
}

class Pentagon extends Polygon {
    public int sides() {
        return 5;  // is not aware of `sides` in Polygon
    }
}
```

```java
Polygon p = new Pentagon();
p.sides(); // -> sides() has private access in Polygon
```

Thus, method `sides` is accessible only for `Pentagon` instances/references:

```java
Pentagon p = new Pentagon();
System.out.println(p.sides());  // -> 5
```

---

If `sides` methods are declared as `static` in both classes having different return types, the code won't compile either:

```java
class Polygon {
    public static void sides() {
        System.out.println("In Polygon sides");
    }    
}

class Pentagon extends Polygon {
    public static int sides() {
        return 5; // sides() in Pentagon cannot hide sides() in Polygon
                  // return type int is not compatible with void
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a method signature is part of the method declaration. **It's the combination of the method name and the parameter list**.

When we talk about the same method signature in the superClass and the subClass + a covariant return type , so we are talking about the Overriding .

### (Same signature + Covariant return type) == Overriding

Comment: your answer does fail to address the issue the OP has

Comment: "Same signature == Overriding" ..except when method is either `private` or `static` since for those polymorthism is not applied.

Comment: @Pshemo yes sure

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can not change the return type if you make an inheritance relation and you use the same signature for a method that exists already in the parent class except if you want to change the return type for a type that is an instance of the original type, otherwise which will cause a syntax error, so you need to change the method signature in the subclass or override it. Suppose that will be applicable, so a subclass will have two methods with the same signature one that is inherited and the other you explicitly write, so when you invoke it, the JVM will not know which one to invoke, so that is not applicable.
Be careful to override a method it should be an instance method and the same signature and the same return type or an instance of the original type and the same access modifier or stronger, otherwise, it will cause a syntax error.

Comment: re *As I know, you can not change the return type ...*   You can, as long as the return type in your override is a subtype of the return type in what you're overriding.  [JLS 8.4.8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#d5e14373).   This is not the case in the OP's question, but you might care to know the general rule.